# IBM MQ for dot-net-standard: depricated types

Tags: .net, nuget, ibm-mq, .net-standard

I have updated my .NET-4.8 code to newest NuGet (v. 9.3.3.1) of IBMXMSDotnetClient and now I can see, that IBM.XMS.IConnectionFactory and many other contract types are deprecated ["Use .NET6 based XMS Client libraries."].

When I inspect the .Net6-DLL inside the NuGet package, I can see, these types still exists, but ***not*** deprecated. Even the implementation looks in first view the same: f.ex. enumeration IBM.XMS.AcknowledgeMode, it's completely identical, but for .NET-Standard it's depricated while in .NET6 it's not depricated.

So I ask myself: What is the message about? Is it indicating that I should go away from old .NET-Framework to .NET6 in general? I mean, with .NET-4.8 I currently need to use the .Net-Standard-DLL (of the NuGet) and I cannot see any other types to use instead of the depreciated ones ...
Or were these depreciate attributes misused?

I also checked the IBM website but couldn't find any useful information about.

Thanks for insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Standard libraries are deprecated and at some point IBM may remove them.

For .NET Framework applications,IBM MQ.NET Framework libraries shipped with the IBM MQ Client should be used.For .NET Framework applications, the MQ .NET Standard should no longer be used as they might be removed in future.

The Attention note in the below link has some information in it

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=environment-using-mq-classes-xms-net

Comment: Indeed, I found the bin\IBM.XMS.dll compiled against .NET-Framework 4.7.2 with the same version as the NuGet (9.3.3.1). However, why this DLL is not included in NuGet, but only .Net-Standard and .Net(-Core), I simply do not comprehend. But as we go direction .NET(-Core) I leave it with the NuGet for now. Thanks for given clarification :)

Comment: You could raise an RFE with IBM for them to make the .NET Framework libraries as well available from Nuget.